# PostgreSQL WHERE count condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having

I have following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.log_id) AS overall_count
FROM 
    "Log" as a, 
    "License" as b 
WHERE 
    a.license_id=7 
AND 
    a.license_id=b.license_id 
AND
    b.limit_call > overall_count
GROUP BY 
    a.license_id;
```

Why do I get this error:

> ERROR:  column "overall_count" does not exist

My table structure:

```
License(license_id, license_name, limit_call, create_date, expire_date)
Log(log_id, license_id, log, call_date)
```

I want to check if a license has reached the limit for calls in a specific month.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
SELECT a.license_id, a.limit_call
     , count(b.license_id) AS overall_count
FROM   "License"  a
LEFT   JOIN "Log" b USING (license_id)
WHERE  a.license_id = 7 
GROUP  BY a.license_id  -- , a.limit_call  -- add in old versions
HAVING a.limit_call > count(b.license_id)
```

Since Postgres 9.1 the primary key covers all columns of a table in the `GROUP BY` clause. In older versions you'd have to add `a.limit_call` to the **`GROUP BY`** list. The [release notes for 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-9-1.html):

> Allow non-`GROUP BY` columns in the query target list when the primary
> key is specified in the `GROUP BY` clause

Further reading:

- [Why can't I exclude dependent columns from `GROUP BY` when I aggregate by a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095987/why-cant-i-exclude-dependent-columns-from-group-by-when-i-aggregate-by-a-key)

The condition you had in the `WHERE` clause has to move to the **`HAVING`** clause since it refers to the result of an aggregate function (*after* `WHERE` has been applied). And you cannot refer to **output columns** (column aliases) in the `HAVING` clause, where you can only reference input columns. So you have to repeat the expression. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
> `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING`
> clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.

I reversed the order of tables in the `FROM` clause and cleaned up the syntax a bit to make it less confusing. **`USING`** is just a notational convenience here.

I used **`LEFT JOIN`** instead of `JOIN`, so you do not exclude licenses without any logs at all.

Only non-null values are counted by `count()`. Since you want to count *related entries* in table `"Log"` it is safer and slightly cheaper to use **`count(b.license_id)`**. This column is used in the join, so we don't have to bother whether the column can be null or not.
`count(*)` is even shorter and slightly faster, yet. If you don't mind to get a count of `1` for `0` rows in the left table, use that.

Aside: I would advise *not* to use [**mixed case identifiers**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in Postgres if possible. Very error prone.

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks. It work for me, but i don't want return b.limit_call in the result. btw what different with 9.1 version ?

Comment: @Hadi: you can remove any column from the SELECT list in this query, no problem. See my amended answer for what's new in 9.1

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, how does the "new in 9.1" work if/since "you" join the primary key with, generally, many "b" records?

Comment: @epox: Once the PK (implicitly `UNIQUE NOT NULL`) is in the `GROUP BY` list, adding any other column of the same table to the same `GROUP BY` list won't change the result. (Those are "functionally dependent".) That's true all the same after joining to many rows.

Comment: I see, So `a` groups are UNIQUE (1 row) groups, and any `a`s column can be used in HAVING since 9.1.

But if "you" needed `b` column in HAVING, you would not be able to use it without COUNT(b.x) or including into GROUP BY. Thanks

Comment: @epox: Yes - only implemented for the PK, though. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62095987/939860

Answer (score 21):

## Pure conditional count(*):

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER(where a.myfield > 0) AS my_count
    FROM "Log" as a 

GROUP BY a.license_id
```

so you:

- get `0` for groups where the condition never meets
- can add as many count(*) columns as you need

---

## Filter-out the groups, having condition mismatch:

NOTE: you cannot use `HAVING b.limit_call > ...`, unless you group by `limit_call`. But you can use an agregate function to map many "limit_calls" in the group into a single value. For example, in your case, you can use `MAX`:

```
  SELECT COUNT(a.log_id) AS overall_count
    FROM "Log" as a 
    JOIN "License" b ON(a.license_id=b.license_id)

GROUP BY a.license_id
  HAVING MAX(b.limit_call) > COUNT(a.log_id)
```

And don't care about duplicating `COUNT(a.log_id)` expression in the first and in the last lines. Postgres will optimize it.

Answer (score 10):

The `where` query doesn't recognize your column alias, and furthermore, you're trying to filter out rows **after** aggregation.  Try:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(a.log_id) AS overall_count
FROM 
"Log" as a, 
"License" as b 
WHERE 
a.license_id=7 
AND 
a.license_id=b.license_id 
GROUP BY 
a.license_id
having b.limit_call > count(a.log_id);
```

The `having` clause is similar to the `where` clause, except that it deals with columns after an aggregation, whereas the `where` clause works on columns before an aggregation.

Also, is there a reason why your table names are enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: i got error "column "b.limit_call" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" when use having

Comment: Then you'll need to group by that column, as well.  Since I don't know the structure of your data, you'll have to figure out the appropriate list of columns for the `group by` clause.