# MySQL query: remove duplicates from ordered list

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

My table is called `items`. It has the columns `item_id` and `source` as well as some other columns.

I want to do a select ordered by `item_id` but I also want to not have any duplicates in the `source` column of the result.

What's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE item_section='sp_500'
ORDER BY item_id DESC
GROUP BY source
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: are you getting an output? is it an error?

Comment: says its not a valid mysql result set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   items
JOIN  (
    SELECT max(item_id) AS item_id
    FROM   items
    WHERE  item_section = 'sp_500'
    GROUP  BY source
    ORDER  BY 1 DESC
    LIMIT  3
    ) i USING (item_id)
```

#### Why?

1) Filter by `item_section = 'sp_500'`

2) Collapse multiple items with the same `source` in a `GROUP BY`, because:

> not have any duplicates in the source column

I take the biggest `item_id` per `source` - seems most plausible and you did not specify.

3) `ORDER BY item_id DESC` to get the greatest ones and LIMIT 3 (without dupes by now).

4) `JOIN` to the original table to get the whole row for the selected `item_id`s.

Comment: by the way the fact that this is way beyond me tells me i really don't know much about SQL and there is alot to learn

Comment: @user557862: We live and learn, right? :) Your problem is a bit tricky - there were 6 answers, already, that didn't get it, either.

Comment: you've got ORDER  BY 1 DESC, but you say ORDER BY item_id DESC in the explanation

Comment: @raquelhortab: It's effectively the same. `ORDER BY 1` is syntax shorthand referencing the first output column. (Plus, in `ORDER BY` "item_id" resolves to the *output* column.) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194088/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119815/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235752/939860 - and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot select everything `*` when you have `GROUP BY` clause. You can select `source` in you query and some other functions like `count(*)`.
Second, you cannot order by `item_id`. You can order by `source` and some other functions.
Third, `order by` should be after `group by`

Comment: but i need the whole record in the result set not just the source

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that `order by item_id` to go after the `group by`. The common rule: group by ... HAVinG ... order by ... .

Answer (score 0):

Change it to below :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT fieldnames FROM items WHERE item_section='sp_500' GROUP BY source ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Here in DISTINCT you have to specify field names.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine `select *` and `group by`.
If you just need to select unique rows, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id, source 
FROM items  
WHERE item_section='sp_500'  
ORDER BY item_id DESC`
```

Comment: this isn't working because i have multiple columns and something is fking up

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE item_section='sp_500'  
GROUP BY source 
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Gudluck!!

Comment: Well,what would be the right order it is ascending or descending?maybe you need to change the desc to asc or add more column name after the first column name in order by,just separate it by a comma ","

Answer (score 0):

change the query

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE item_section='sp_500'
GROUP BY source
ORDER BY item_id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

if no results are there then try to remove the where clause or change the value of item_section you may be getting no output for this item_section

hope this helps