# In Postgresql how to order by date while keeping custom date format

Tags: postgresql, date, formatting, sql-order-by

The issue is that using to_char will turn order by date into order by ascii. Example:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM baz ORDER BY foo;
```

I would like to format foo using to_char, but doing this will affect the order:

```
SELECT to_char(foo,'dd/MM/yyyy') as foo, bar FROM baz ORDER BY foo;
```

Because foo now is of type text. There is a way to correctly do this? Or only in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different alias for the formatted column:

```
SELECT to_char(foo,'dd/MM/yyyy') as formatted_foo, 
       bar 
FROM baz 
ORDER BY foo;
```

As an alternative if you need to keep the foo alias:

```
select foo,
       bar
from (
  SELECT to_char(foo,'dd/MM/yyyy') as foo,
         foo as foo_date 
         bar 
  FROM baz 
) t
order by foo_date
```

Comment: Thanks, even there's a way to keep the original column name.

Answer (score 7):

The proper and simple solution is:

```sql
SELECT to_char(b.foo,'DD/MM/YYYY') as foo, b.bar
FROM   baz b
ORDER  BY b.foo;
```

The formatted date column `foo` is a completely new column for the query planner, that happens to conflict with the table column `foo`. In `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses output column names take precedence over input columns. The unqualified name `foo` would refer to the output column.

To use the original table column in the `ORDER BY` clause, just **table-qualify the column**.

I table-qualified all column names to be clear. Would only be required in the `ORDER BY` clause in this case. Table alias `b` is just for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with

```
SELECT foo AS foo_date, to_char(foo,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS foo, bar 
FROM baz 
ORDER BY foo_date;
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to not pulling foo twice would be:

```
SELECT
  to_char(foo,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS foo -- Alias precedes original column name
  ,bar
FROM
  baz
ORDER BY
  CAST(foo AS DATE) -- Explicit cast ensures date order instead of text
;
```

The native PostgreSQL version of that would be:

```
SELECT
  to_char(foo,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS foo -- Alias precedes original column name
  ,bar
FROM
  baz
ORDER BY
  foo::DATE -- Explicit cast ensures date order instead of text
;
```

Comment: That's just unnecessary complication for no benefit.