# Sort columns independently, such that all nulls are last per column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, pivot, full-outer-join

Here is an example table called `animal`:

```
name | color
------------
fox  | brown
fox  | red
dog  | gold
```

Now, what I want is this result:

```
fox   | dog
-------------
brown | gold
red   |
```

The names should be columns of the result with the different color values as rows.

My first thought was like:

```
SELECT color
FROM animal
WHERE name='fox'

[some sort of join?]

SELECT color 
FROM animal
WHERE name='dog'
```

But I don't know what kind of join would do the trick.

Second thought:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'fox' THEN color ELSE NULL END AS fox,
CASE WHEN name = 'dog' THEN color ELSE NULL END AS dog
FROM animal
```

This returns:

```
fox   | dog
-----------
red   | 
brown |
      | gold
```

I would like to move the null values in this table to the end.
I tried to:

```
ORDER BY CASE name
        WHEN 'fox' THEN fox
        WHEN 'dog' THEN dog
    END
```

But I'm not sure if this is really what I want and Postgres is nagging that fox is not a column although I can do `ORDER BY fox`.

Maybe my approach is total nonsense or there is some kind of coalesce magic that can do the trick?

Comment: What about ORDER BY something NULLS LAST ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that there would be a "natural" order in a table (like in a spreadsheet), but there is not. Without `ORDER BY`, rows are returned in *arbitrary* order - which often happens to be identical to input order for small tables that have not been updated, yet.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY color) AS rn, * 
   FROM   animal
   )
SELECT f.color AS fox, d.color AS dog
FROM        (SELECT rn, color FROM cte WHERE name = 'fox') f
FULL   JOIN (SELECT rn, color FROM cte WHERE name = 'dog') d USING (rn)
ORDER  BY rn;
```

#### Major points

Attach sequential numbers per color for each type of animal separately in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

The [**`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) is crucial, since the number of rows for 'fox' and 'dog' differ.

Colors are sorted alphabetically, `NULL` values are last automatically in default `ASCENDING` sort order. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

This only scans the table *once*.

Explanation for the error message you got (*"fox" is not a column*):

- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815)
- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

Comment: Thank you for this very clean approach. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
WITH fox_color as 
(SELECT color as fox, row_number() rn
 FROM animal
 WHERE name='fox'),
dog_color as 
(SELECT color as dog, row_number() rn
 FROM animal
 WHERE name='dog')
SELECT fox, dog
FROM fox_color 
JOIN dog_color ON fox_color.rn = dog_color.rn
```