# Get distinct individual column values (not distinct pairs) from two tables in single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join, distinct-values

I have two tables like the following. One is for sport talents of some people and second for arts talents. One may not have a sport talent to list and same applies for art talent.

```
CREATE TABLE SPORT_TALENT(name varchar(10), TALENT varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE ART_TALENT(name varchar(10), TALENT varchar(10));

INSERT INTO SPORT_TALENT(name, TALENT) VALUES
  ('Steve', 'Footbal')
 ,('Steve', 'Golf')
 ,('Bob'  , 'Golf')
 ,('Mary' , 'Tennnis');

INSERT INTO ART_TALENT(name, TALENT) VALUES
  ('Steve', 'Dancer')
, ('Steve', 'Singer')
, ('Bob'  , 'Dancer')
, ('Bob'  , 'Singer')
, ('John' , 'Dancer');
```

Now I want to list down sport talent and art talent of one person. I would like to avoid duplication. But I don't mind if there is a "null" in any output. I tried the following

```
select distinct sport_talent.talent as s_talent,art_talent.talent as a_talent
from sport_talent
JOIN art_talent on sport_talent.name=art_talent.name
where (sport_talent.name='Steve' or art_talent.name='Steve');

 s_talent | a_talent 
----------+----------
 Footbal  | Dancer
 Golf     | Singer
 Footbal  | Singer
 Golf     | Dancer
```

I would like to avoid redundancy and need something like the following (distinct values of sport talents + distinct values of art talents).

```
 s_talent | a_talent 
----------+----------
 Footbal  | Dancer
 Golf     | Singer
```

As mentioned in subject, I am not looking for distinct combinations. But at the same time, it's OK if there are some records with "null" value in one column. I am relatively new to SQL.

Comment: So, in your result, there is no relationship between the s_talent values and the a_talent values. You simply have two independent lists shown side-by-side?

Comment: @Vimt if you look data steve played football and golf, if you join this result with art talent for steve it has dancer and singer, therefore sing played football and golf and singer played golf and football. it's what explain the 4 rows résults

Comment: Are you running the current version Postgres 9.4? (Always add your version!)

Comment: @Turophile: Yes, two idependent lists shown side by side. No relation between s_talent and a_talent. Anyway I got the answer from Erwin and kordirko

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT s_talent, a_talent
FROM (
  SELECT distinct on (talent) talent as s_talent,
        dense_rank() over (order by  talent) as x
  FROM SPORT_TALENT
  WHERE name='Steve'
) x
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT distinct on (talent) talent as a_talent,
        dense_rank() over (order by  talent) as x
  FROM ART_TALENT
  WHERE name='Steve'
) y
ON x.x = y.x
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66e04/3

Answer (score 0):

There are no duplicates in your query. Each of the four records in your query return is unique. This result may not be what you want, but seems like its problem is not the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

#### Postgres 9.4

... introduces [`unnest()` with multiple arguments](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html). Does exactly what you want, and should be fast, too. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)

> The special table function `UNNEST` may be called with any number of
>   array parameters, and it returns a corresponding number of columns, as
>   if `UNNEST` (Section 9.18) had been called on each parameter separately
>   and combined using the `ROWS FROM` construct.

About `ROWS FROM`:

- [Compare result of two table functions using one column from each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808819/compare-result-of-two-table-functions-using-one-column-from-each/28809191#28809191)

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest(
         ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT talent FROM sport_talent WHERE name = 'Steve')
       , ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT talent FROM art_talent WHERE name = 'Steve')
       ) AS t(s_talent, a_talent);
```

#### Postgres 9.3 or older

```
SELECT s_talent, a_talent
FROM  (
   SELECT talent AS s_talent, row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM   sport_talent
   WHERE  name = 'Steve'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT talent AS a_talent, row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM   art_talent
   WHERE  name = 'Steve'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a USING (rn);
```

Similar previous answers with more explanation:

- [What type of JOIN to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034827/what-type-of-join-to-use/28035613#28035613)
- [Sort columns independently, such that all nulls are last per column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745019/sort-columns-independently-such-that-all-nulls-are-last-per-column/27751938#27751938)

This is similar to what [@kordirko posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289831/939860), but uses `GROUP BY` to get distinct talents, which is evaluated *before* window functions. So we only need a bare [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) and not the more expensive `dense_rank()`.

About the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7ede3/7)

Comment: Thanks @Erwin. Exactly what I wanted. I am using Postgres 9.2. Tested all the combinations. I will be spending some time to understand it...