# Which of queries is more efficient? Inner Join vs subquery ? Sum case vs having

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I am using PostgreSql 9. I have a simply question.
Which of queries is more efficient?

```
SELECT users_sessions.session_id, users_sessions.series 
FROM users_sessions 
WHERE users_sessions.user_id = 8 
AND users_sessions.session_id IN (
    SELECT session_id 
    FROM sessions_history 
    GROUP BY sessions_history.session_id 
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN sessions_history.action = 2 THEN 1 END) = 0
)
```

**VS.**

```
SELECT US8.session_id,Us8.series

FROM

( SELECT us.session_id as S_ID, us.series 
        FROM users_sessions as US
        WHERE US.user_id = 8 ) AS US8
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SH.session_id as SH_ID
        FROM session_history as SH
        WHERE SH.action <> 2) AS SH2    
ON US8.session_id = SH2.session_id
```

Comment: Check the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: Well, have you tried them? The second one doesn't even seem valid. Test them, write down all the results and then ask one good question.

Comment: Your version of Postgres? "9" is not a valid version. "9.2" or "9.3" is ...

Comment: I think second query is bad.

Comment: @KamilJ: It is. You cannot reference column aliases from the `SELECT` list ("output columns") in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Are you sure?

Comment: @KamilJ: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815

Comment: @KamilJ - Purely commenting on Erwin's point; correct syntax would be `HAVING SUM(1) = 0` *(repeating the logic from the SELECT clause in the HAVING clause)* or if you didn't want to repeat yourself; `SELECT * FROM (<your query, without a HAVING clause>) AS aggregate WHERE s = 0`.

Comment: @MatBailie: Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution uses a NOT EXISTS, which is an exact translation of what you seem to ask:

Give me the sessions where no action 2 exists:

```
SELECT session_id, series 
FROM users_sessions as us
WHERE users_sessions.user_id = 8 
AND NOT EXISTS
 (  SELECT * 
    FROM sessions_history as sh
    WHERE action = 2
    AND us.session_id = sh.session_id 
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd query <strike>is</strike> was syntactically invalid. You cannot reference column aliases from the `SELECT` list ("output columns") in the `HAVING` clause.

Either way, both queries are not good. If you really want to find a combination of `(user_id, action)` that does not exist, try instead:

```
SELECT t.*, 0 AS s
FROM  (SELECT 8 AS user_id, 2 AS action) t
LEFT  JOIN (
            users_sessions  us
       JOIN session_history sh USING (session_id)
           ) USING (user_id, action)
WHERE  sh.session_id IS NULL;
```

I introduce a derived table with a single row in subquery `t` and `LEFT JOIN` to the combination of the two base tables. Only returns a row, if the combination does *not* exist.
Assuming the column names `user_id` and `action` appear only once in both tables. Else use the more explicit condition for the second join:

```
ON t.user_id = us.user_id AND t.action = sh.action
```

Details:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

#### Alternative

Probably faster, yet:

```
SELECT t.*, 0 AS s
FROM  (SELECT 8 AS user_id, 2 AS action) t
LEFT   JOIN users_sessions  us USING (user_id)
LEFT   JOIN session_history sh USING (action, session_id)
WHERE  sh.session_id IS NULL;
```

The `USING` construct is safe either way in this example.

Comment: Are you really a fan of `USING`?  Doesn't it get really untidy when your queries *also* include range look-ups, etc?

Comment: @MatBailie: I have a soft spot for short, concise code. For persisted queries it's safer to use the explicit form to be less vulnerable to later schema changes to the underlying tables. The first `USING` clause in the example is safe, though.

Answer (score 1):

My tuppence worth;

I can interpret your intentions in two different ways, and have different solutions for each *(my preferred solution being first in each case)*;

**Sessions that have at least one History record where the action <> 2**
*(And not caring how many History records there are where action = 2)*

```
SELECT
    us.session_id,
    us.series
FROM
    users_sessions   AS us
INNER JOIN
    session_history  AS sh
        ON  sh.session_id  = us.session_id
        AND sh.action     <> 2
WHERE
    us.user_id = 8
GROUP BY
    us.session_id,
    us.series
```

or

```
SELECT
    us.session_id,
    us.series
FROM
    users_sessions   AS us
WHERE
        us.user_id = 8
    AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM session_history  AS sh
                 WHERE sh.session_id  = us.session_id
                   AND sh.action     <> 2
               )
```

or

```
SELECT
    us.session_id,
    us.series
FROM
    users_sessions   AS us
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        session_id
    FROM
        session_history
    WHERE
        sh.action <> 2
    GROUP BY
        session_id
)
    AS sh
        ON  sh.session_id  = us.session_id
WHERE
    us.user_id = 8
```

**Sessions that have no History records where action = 2**
*(but can have other History records)*

```
SELECT
    us.session_id,
    us.series
FROM
    users_sessions   AS us
LEFT JOIN
    session_history  AS sh
        ON  sh.session_id = us.session_id
        AND sh.action     = 2
WHERE
        us.user_id     = 8
    AND sh.session_id IS NULL

-- No GROUP BY needed this time
```

or

```
SELECT
    us.session_id,
    us.series
FROM
    users_sessions   AS us
WHERE
        us.user_id = 8
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM session_history  AS sh
                     WHERE sh.session_id = us.session_id
                       AND sh.action     = 2
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?

```
SELECT US8.session_id,Us8.series

FROM

( SELECT us.session_id as S_ID, us.series 
        FROM users_sessions as US
        WHERE US.user_id = 8 ) AS US8
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SH.session_id as SH_ID
        FROM session_history as SH
        WHERE SH.action <> 2) AS SH2    
ON US8.session_id = SH2.session_id
```

Comment: Is it possible for a `session_id` to have Zero corresponding rows in `session_history`?  If so you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` type of look-up, as per the other answers here.

Comment: You would first need to define *exactly* (in the question) what the query is supposed to do. There a quite a few fine points here.

Comment: Is is possible for a `session_id` to have Multiple corresponding rows in `session_history`?  If so, your `SH2` sub-query should have a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to prevent duplication of results.