# Why am I getting column "ended" does not exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I am trying to do a conditional `ORDER BY` in SQL but I am getting an error: `column "ended" does not exist` pointing to the 'case when "ended"' part of the query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM SUBMISSION_DEADLINE)
       -EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now())) AS "datediff"
    , (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM SUBMISSION_DEADLINE)>EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now())) AS "ended", *
FROM imdown_api_v1_contest
ORDER BY "ended" DESC, case when "ended" = true then "datediff" else "-datediff" END ASC;
```

I need to grab the contests that haven't ended first and order those by the one ending soonest first. Then I need all the ones that have ended and order those by the ones that ended most recently.

Comment: One option is to move your query (without the `order by`) into a subquery and then add the `order by` back.  That should recognize the `ended` column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is broken or inefficient in multiple places, not just the illegal reference to a column alias. This might do what you intend:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() - submission_deadline) AS datediff
     , now() > submission_deadline AS ended  -- I inverted your expression!
     , *
FROM   imdown_api_v1_contest
ORDER  BY 2  -- positional reference to output column
     , @(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() - submission_deadline))
```

Typically, contests that "ended" have a `submission_deadline` in the ***past***, so `now() > submission_deadline AS ended`, not the other way round.

To fix your primary syntax error I use a positional reference instead of the column alias. Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815)

Related example:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

To achieve your desired order I use the [absolute value operator **`@`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html).

Comment: is there a way to make these work with LIMIT and OFFSET clauses?

Comment: @Tyler: I don't see a problem for `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` here ... Maybe start a new question to present your case clearly? Either way, consider the updated query for the question at hand.

Answer (score 2):

column `ended` is not defined when order by is executed, sql executes query in next order:

1. from
2. where
3. order
4. select

so, you need either copy your full expression into `order by` clause or use sub-queries, like:

```
select * from (
    SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM SUBMISSION_DEADLINE)-EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now())) AS "datediff", (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM SUBMISSION_DEADLINE)>EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now())) AS "ended", *
    FROM imdown_api_v1_contest
) tmpq
ORDER BY "ended" DESC, case when "ended" = true then "datediff" else "-datediff" END ASC
```