# Finding the count of duplicates between two values within a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have this problem:

> Create a function `skillsInRange(n1 int, n2 int)` that returns the count of Westerosis that have at least `n1` skills and at most `n2` skills.

With the relevant table:

```
INSERT INTO WesterosiSkill(wid, skill) VALUES
  (1001,'Archery'), (1001,'Politics'), (1002,'Archery'),
  (1002,'Politics'), (1004,'Politics'), (1004,'Archery'),
  (1005,'Politics'), (1005,'Archery'), (1005,'Swordsmanship'),
  (1006,'Archery'), (1006,'HorseRiding'), ...
```

It seems obvious that we only need to count the duplicate values in `wid` (first column). And then our second condition is only keeping the ones that have between `n1` and `n2` occurrences.

So I created this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION skillsInRange (n1 int, n2 int)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
SELECT COUNT(wid) AS wcount
FROM westerosiSkill
GROUP BY wid
HAVING wcount BETWEEN n1 AND n2
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And a few variants of it. None of which have worked. In this version, it tells me that `wcount` doesn't exist, even when I change `HAVING` to `WHERE`.

The `SELECT COUNT ... GROUP BY` returns the incorrect number of occurrences for each `wid`. And any of the `HAVING` clauses I've tried returns the incorrect number of occurrences between these two values, or in this instance, is syntactically incorrect due to the aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need two levels of aggregation:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION skillsinrange (n1 int, n2 int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT count(*)::int
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*)::int AS wcount
   FROM   westerosiSkill
   GROUP  BY wid
   ) sub
WHERE wcount BETWEEN n1 AND n2;
$func$;
```

This is assuming that `(wid, skill)` is the PK, so both columns are defined `NOT NULL`, and the combination `UNIQUE`. Else you need to do more.

The function wrapper seems arbitrary. You might just use the plain query.

The cast to `integer` is just because you show a function signature with type `integer` for input and output. You might use `bigint` instead and ditch the casts.

For the error messages you saw, consider [the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
> `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING`
> clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.

See:

- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815)

Comment: This is returning the wrong value when either n1 or n2 = 0. But the other non-zero cases appear correct.

Comment: A count of zero doesn't make sense, unless there is a separate "westerosis" table you neglected to mention ...